# How to make behavior binding on customer control in Xamarin form or dotnet maui?

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I created a customer entry which contain a label for error message

```xml
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ExampleApp.Contols.CustomerEntry"
             Title="Customer"
             x:Name="AppEntry">
   <Entry x:Name="ControlEntry"
          BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor, Source={x:Reference AppEntry}}"/>
   <Label x:Name="ConrolErrorMessage"
          Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, Source={x:Reference AppEntry}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now using the control, in any page.

```xml
<CustomerEntry 
      x:Name="Password"
      BackgroundColor="Blue">
      <controls:EntryControl.Behaviors>
          <toolkit:TextValidationBehavior 
                  InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntry}"
                  MinimumLength="10"
                  MaximumLength="100" />
      </controls:EntryControl.Behaviors>
</CustomerEntry>
```

The `InvalidEntry` style is simple:

```xml
<Style
   x:Key="InvalidEntry"
   TargetType="controls:CustomerEntry">
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Now the behavior is not working. Is it possible to bind pass the behavior to the `Entry` of the customer control?
I try to make the entry of the customer control as follow:

```xml
   <Entry x:Name="ControlEntry"
          BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor, Source={x:Reference AppEntry}}"
          Behaviors="{Binding Behaviors, Source={x:Reference AppEntry}}"/>
```

The above code didn't work.

Comment: What's the code of `CustomerEntry `,`ErrorMessage` and `BackgroundColor`? Could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: `CustomerEntry` is a customer control that have `ErrorMessage` as biding property.  The first `Grid` is the code of `CustomerEntry`. It has an `Entry` and a `Label`. The `Entry`  background color is bind to the `Grid` background color